# bash script for directory listing with extra information

Tags: bash

I need to know how what command or commands I can use in a `bash` script that would give me a directory listing like this (note the extra lines at the end).

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   backups
drwxr-xr-x  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   c_source
drwxr-xr-x  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   cgi_files
drwxr-xr-x  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   cgi_scripts
drwxr-xr-x  4 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   ny
drwxr-xr-x  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   perl
-rw-r--r--  1 dshoe users   1954 2010-10-28 18:41   pers
drwxrwxrwx  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   public_html
-rw-r--r--  1 dshoe users   3392 2010-10-28 18:41   sales
-rwxr--r--  1 dshoe users   228  2010-10-28 18:41   sargs
drwx------  2 dshoe users   4096 2010-10-28 18:41   scripts
-rw-r--r--  1 dshoe users   131  2010-10-28 18:41   setup

Total bytes:    17899
Total files:    4
Directories:    9
And scripts:    1
```

The standard `ls` command cannot do this so I'm wondering what I can use in my `bash` script to achieve this.

Comment: No, I don't believe this is out of place here. This is clearly asking for a script to do the work (ie, programming).

Comment: There is no standard `ls` argument that can add the last part with the totals. You have to make a script to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base command you want to use is `ls -l` but you're going to need to post-process the output to get those last four lines.

For example, here's one that will get you the first three items plus the fourth which I've assumed is the number of regular files with the execute bit set for the owner:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
tmpfile=/tmp/tmpfile.$$
ls -l | tee ${tmpfile}
echo
echo "Total bytes:" $(awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}' ${tmpfile})
echo "Total files:" $(grep -v '^total ' ${tmpfile} | grep -v '^d' | wc -l)
echo "Directories:" $(grep -v '^total ' ${tmpfile} | grep '^d' | wc -l)
echo "And scripts:" $(grep -v '^total ' ${tmpfile} | grep '^-..x' | wc -l)
rm -f ${tmpfile}
```

which outputs:

```
total 1589
-rwxr-xr-x   1 pax root      57 Oct  3 14:24 Cygwin.bat
-rw-r--r--   1 pax root    7022 Oct  3 14:24 Cygwin.ico
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root 1048576 Oct  3 14:20 bin
dr-xr-xr-x   4 pax None       0 Nov  3 17:06 cygdrive
drwxrwxr-x+  1 pax None       0 Oct  3 14:05 dev
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root   32768 Oct  3 14:20 etc
drwxrwxrwt+  1 pax root       0 Oct  3 14:13 home
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root  524288 Oct  3 14:19 lib
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root       0 Oct  3 13:35 opt
dr-xr-xr-x  10 pax None       0 Nov  3 17:06 proc
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root       0 Oct  3 13:59 sbin
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax None       0 Oct  3 14:10 srv
drwxrwxrwt+  1 pax root    4096 Nov  3 17:06 tmp
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root    4096 Oct  3 14:10 usr
drwxr-xr-x+  1 pax root    4096 Oct  3 14:20 var

Total bytes: 1624999
Total files: 2
Directories: 13
And scripts: 1
```

However, I'm not entirely sure how you're deciding what a script is. If it's different to what I assumed, it's still doable, you just have to figure out what the actual command is (tell us what you want to measure to get the value).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just got back from my linux midterm and it really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following command:

```
$ ls -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is:
`ls -al`